# How can I combine xslt and regex to find specific strings

Tags: regex, xslt

I am very new to XSL, and learning regex, so I might be going about this incorrectly, but I would like a way to find strings in XML files, and sometimes those strings must appear in specific elements, or **not** in specific elements.

e.g., `(\w+)\ (\,|\.|\:|\;|\?)` finds orphan punctuation but I don't want to search inside `<screen>` or similar elements, which typically contain commands, output, and so on, and where orphan punctuation is commonplace.

By way of example:

This is an error , because there is a space before the comma and before the period .

This is not an error, because `<command>cd ../</command>` is a valid command.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

To use regular expressions with XSLT you need XSLT 2.0 or later, and it's then very simple:

```
<!-- Match errors -->
<xsl:template match="text()[matches(., '\s[.,:;?!]')]"
              mode="look-for-bad-punctuation" priority="5">
  <bad-punctuation-found/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Match unchecked elements -->
<xsl:template match="screen/text() | command/text()"
             mode="look-for-bad-punctuation" priority="6">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Match elements with no error -->
<xsl:template match="text()"
             mode="look-for-bad-punctuation" priority="4">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I'm testing this right now (I had to find a 2.0 processor) and I'm still coming to terms with how it all fits together. Right now it just seems to output the text of my XML file, with no indication of the error that I added for testing.

Comment: Then I suggest a new question in which you provide your source document, stylesheet, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't include `mode="look-for-bad-punctuation"` in your apply-templates call. You can of course use the default mode if you prefer, so long as you do it consistently.

Comment: reposted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63369012/combine-xslt-and-regex-to-find-strings